# Google Analytics Multiple Custom Dimension

Tags: google-analytics

I am working on Google Analytics chart on my site and in the tracking code I want two add two custom dimension (One is a User ID). I am doing it this way, am I doing it right ?
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX', {'userId': spUserId});
ga('set', {
    'dimension1': spUserId,
    'dimension2': jobAidId
});
ga('send', 'pageview');

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct:

```
ga('set', {'dimensionX': valueX, 'dimensionY': valueY, 'dimensionZ': valueZ});
ga('send','pageview');
```

You could also send them with other hits too:

```
ga('set', {'dimensionX': valueX, 'dimensionY': valueY, 'dimensionZ': valueZ});
ga('send','event', 'cat', 'action', 'label');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What is ga('send','event', 'cat', 'action', 'label'); though ?

Comment: That sends an event hit: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: When you use set command, it is behaved like global variable. If you set it up directly with send command, it is behaving like locally setted variable.

Comment: To help clarify further- setting metrics and dimensions does nothing until they are sent with some kind of hit type: `pageview` and `event` are most common, but they can be sent with `timing` too (and probably even `exception`).