# Google Analytics - How to send multiple dimensions for an event in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

I am new to Google Analytics. In my project i have to send multiple dimensions for an event. Actually i need to raise an event with two dimensions, event raises twice because i am raising the event individually for each dimension. I googled for multiple dimensions and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099708/google-analytics-multiple-custom-dimension), here i'm lil confused to convert it in to iOS (i mean in Objective-C). 
Here is my code which i call for each dimension.

```
[tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:[eventDict valueForKey:@"category"]
                                                           action:[eventDict valueForKey:@"action"]
                                                            label:[eventDict valueForKey:@"label"]
                                                            value:[eventDict valueForKey:@"value"]]
                    set:nameStr forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:indexval]] build]];
```

Please suggest me a best solution for mutiple dimensions for an event.

Comment: Try this code. It works for me.

[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker trackEventWithCategory:@"UIAction"
                                                 withAction:@"buttonLoginPress"
                                                  withLabel:@"Next button to home page"
                                                  withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution this will help you, this solution worked for me.

**Note -  You need to set it to tracker,google analytics framework internally it sends the data that is send to the tracker. You can check by printing the logs.**

For Screen Views you can do this.

```
 + (void)trackScreenStatusScreenName:(NSString *)screenName 
    {
        id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
        [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:screenName];

        NSString * userStages = @"Some string";//dimension for user stages
        NSString * userID = @"Some user ID";
        NSString * contentStages = @"Some stage";

       [tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]
                      value:userID];
       [tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:2]
                          value:userStages];

       [tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:3] value:contentStages];

       [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];

    }
```

For event you can do this

```
+ (void)createEventWithCategory:(NSString *)eventCategory action:(NSString *)action label:(NSString *)label value:(NSNumber *)value
{
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    NSString * userStages = @"Some string";//dimension for user stages
            NSString * userID = @"Some user ID";
            NSString * contentStages = @"Some stage";

           [tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]
                          value:userID];
           [tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:2]
                              value:userStages];
           [tracker set:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:3] value:contentStages];

    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:eventCategory
                                                          action:action
                                                           label:label
                                                           value:value] build]];
}
```